# Update ngmodel from Select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

We're attempting to display a customer's information based upon the contact they select.  When we use `ng-options` it works as expected.  We are, however, using [Ui.Select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) and "ui-select2 is incompatible with ." So we are forced to use ng-repeat and it isn't working as expected.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.contacts = 
  [  { 
    'CntctKey': '331518',
    'Name': 'Cheryl',
    'Phone': '55555115',
    'PrimaryCntct': '0'
     } ,  
    { 
    'CntctKey': '118431',
    'EmailAddr': 'pizzamaybe@gmail.com',
    'Name': "Stephanie Pizza",
    'Phone': '555552255',
    'PrimaryCntct': '1'
 }  ];

});
```

HTML

```
  <h3>With ng-options</h3>
      <select ng-model="contactedPerson" ng-options="contact.Name for contact in contacts"></select>
      <input ng-model="contactedPerson.Phone"/>
      <input ng-model="contactedPerson.CntctKey"/>
      <br>
      <h3>With ng-repeat</h3>
      <select ng-model="contactPerson1" >
        <option ng-repeat="contact in contacts" value="{{contact}}">{{contact.Name}}</option>
      </select>
      <input ng-model="contactPerson1"/>
      <input ng-model="contactPerson1.Cntctkey"/>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9D9LTCnBOGAo2ftA1jbU

You can see that with `ng-repeat` it shows the object but we can't drill it into it any further.

Is there a good way to do this besides using `ng-options`?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `value="{{contact}}"`

This causes angular to print the object as a JSON string.

So when the value gets assigned from the ng-model in the select list, the variable is assigned a string value i.e.
`"{"CntctKey":"331518","Name":"Cheryl","Phone":"55555115","PrimaryCntct":"0"}"`, rather than the object's itself.

This is why in your plnkr, your second field which has `ng-model="contactPerson1.CntctKey"` has no value, because for a string, this property is undefined.

to fix this you can just use the index of the array element to reference the object.
You can access this index by using ng-repeat's key mapping `(contactKey, contact) in contacts`.

Or if you are just storing everything in a flat, contiguous array (like in the example), just use ng-repeat's `$index` variable.

i.e.

```
<select ng-model="contactPerson1Index" >
    <option ng-repeat="contact in contacts" value="{{$index}}">{{contact.Name}}</option>
</select>
<input ng-model="contacts[contactPerson1Index].Phone"/>
<input ng-model="contacts[contactPerson1Index].CntctKey"/>
```

See updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4thQmsZamN3tt0xpscj9

for more info on key mapping and ng-repeats internal variables, see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat